# Why does HttpCacheability.Private suppress ETags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, caching

While writing a custom IHttpHandler I came across a behavior that I didn't expect concerning the HttpCachePolicy object.

My handler calculates and sets an entity-tag (using the SetETag method on the HttpCachePolicy associated with the current response object). If I set the cache-control to public using the SetCacheability method everything works like a charm and the server sends along the e-tag header. If I set it to private the e-tag header will be suppressed.

Maybe I just haven't looked hard enough but I haven't seen anything in the HTTP/1.1 spec that would justify this behavior. Why wouldn't you want to send E-Tag to browsers while still prohibiting proxies from storing the data?

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext ctx) {
        ctx.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        ctx.Response.Cache.SetETag("\"static\"");
        ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        ctx.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }
}
```

Will return

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
```

But if we change it to public it'll return

```
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11
Etag: "static"
```

I've run this on the ASP.NET development server and IIS6 so far with the same results. Also I'm unable to explicitly set the ETag using

```
Response.AppendHeader("ETag", "static")
```

**Update**: It's possible to append the ETag header manually when running in IIS7, I suspect this is caused by the tight integration between ASP.NET and the IIS7 pipeline.

**Clarification**: It's a long question but the core question is this: **why does ASP.NET do this, how can I get around it and should I?**

**Update**: I'm going to accept [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824/why-does-httpcacheabilityprivate-suppress-etags#34004) since it's essentially correct (go Tony!). I found that if you want to emulate the HttpCacheability.Private fully you can set the cacheability to ServerAndPrivate but you also have call cache.[SetOmitVaryStar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setomitvarystar.aspx)(true) otherwise the cache will add the **Vary: *** header to the output and you don't want that. I'll edit that into the answer when I get edit permissions (or if you see this Tony perhaps you could edit your answer to include that call?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need to use HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate

That should give you cache-control: private in the headers and let you set an ETag.

The documentation on that needs to be a bit better.

**Edit:** Markus found that you also have call cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true) otherwise the cache will add the Vary: * header to the output and you don't want that.

Comment: I don't know if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2633452/1869660) to a different question describes the reason why @Markus adds the call to `SetOmitVaryStar()`, but as of ASP.NET 4.0 it may not be needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately if you look at `System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UpdateCachedHeaders()` in .NET Reflector you see that there's an if statement specifically checking that the Cacheability is not Private before doing any ETag stuff. In any case, I've always found that `Last-Modified/If-Modified-Since` works well for our data and is a bit easier to monitor in Fiddler anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If like me you're unhappy with the workaround mentioned here of using Cacheability.ServerAndPrivate, and you really want to use Private instead - perhaps because you are customising pages individually for users and it makes no sense to cache on the server - then at least in .NET 3.5 you can set ETag through Response.Headers.Add and this works fine.

N.B. if you do this you have to implement the comparison of the client headers yourself and the HTTP 304 response handling - not sure if .NET takes care of this for you under normal circumstances.

Comment: You can always just call `HttpCachePolicy.SetNoServerCaching` to disable output caching (i.e. server caching). This overrides the "server" part of `HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate`.

Comment: @WilliamGross This should probably be the accepted answer! Thank you.