# How to cache asp.net web site for better performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching

I am a web designer and usually design corporate web sites which often does not require update. So I want to cache the output for one day. How can I do this?

Also any suggestions for better performance for asp.net on slow servers are accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend you to follow this rules in order to improve performance in general

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

If you install the YSlow for firebug it will validate all these rules for you.

And regarding to cache in particular I recommend you to read this tutorial. Cache is a very extensive topic and it's not easy to explain everything in 10 lines :-)

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL

Specifically talking about the output cache directive for ASP NET pages, it's quite simple to use. Here you have the reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

But please take into account that is important to use the cache for pages and also for other resources as css, JS and images.

Comment: please don't link to solutions, as they go stale, like the link above

Answer (score 7):

**Be aware that ASP.NET caching has a [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/254940/the-serverandclient-parameter-with-the-outputcache-page-directive-does-not-cache-on-the-client-without-code) since 1.0, that can effectively disable client-side caching.**
That is why the [`HttpCachePolicy.SetOmitVaryStar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setomitvarystar(VS.80).aspx) method was added later as a workaround.
Developers should use it, but unfortunately, it seems that few of them know about the above method.
In response, the behavior is changed in ASP.NET 4.0, as detailed in the [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes list](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes/#0.1__Toc256770157):

> In ASP.NET 1.0, a bug caused cached pages that specified Location="ServerAndClient" as an output–cache setting to emit a Vary:* HTTP header in the response. This had the effect of telling client browsers to never cache the page locally.
>
> In ASP.NET 1.1, the System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.SetOmitVaryStar method was added, which you could call to suppress the Vary:* header. This method was chosen because changing the emitted HTTP header was considered a potentially breaking change at the time. However, developers have been confused by the behavior in ASP.NET, and bug reports suggest that developers are unaware of the existing SetOmitVaryStar behavior.
>
> In ASP.NET 4, the decision was made to fix the root problem. The Vary:* HTTP header is no longer emitted from responses that specify the following directive:
>
> <OutputCache Location="ServerAndClient" %>
>
> As a result, SetOmitVaryStar is no longer needed in order to suppress the Vary:* header.
>
> In applications that specify Location="ServerAndClient" in the @ OutputCache directive on a page, you will now see the behavior implied by the name of the Location attribute's value – that is, pages will be cacheable in the browser without requiring that you call the SetOmitVaryStar method.
>
> If pages in your application must emit Vary:*, call the AppendHeader method, as in the following example:
>
> HttpResponse.AppendHeader("Vary","*");
>
> Alternatively, you can change the value of the output caching Location attribute to "Server".

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I'll start using caching in my Asp.Net 4 applications.

Answer (score 4):

You use the outputcache directive

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachingaspnet.aspx

**10 Tips for Writing High-Performance Web Applications**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx