# How to get full file path of FilePathResult file in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file

I want to get last modification date of the file that is returned by action method. I think I need a full file path. `FilePathResult` has property `FileName`.

Does this property return full file path or just a name? If so, can I somehow obtain full path to that file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the full path to the file. Example:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File(Server.MapPath("~/web.config"), "text/xml");
}
```

and then:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var fileResult = filterContext.Result as FilePathResult;
        if (fileResult != null)
        {
            // here you will get the full absolute path to the file,
            // for example c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MvcApplication1\web.config
            string fileName = fileResult.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I was counting on that it returns full file path. I want to set last modification date of the file (first I need to get it). For some reason I can't set (or get) the modification date properly. Can You check my update please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlekseiChepovoi, that's a completely different questoin which has nothing to do with your original question and is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914228/client-side-caching-using-last-modified-header-and-outputcacheattribute-in-asp-n Please do not post duplicate questions. Here you initially asked if the `FileName` property returns the full path to the file and the answer to this is yes. If you need to discuss some other code let that happen at the appropriate place.