# Why do my ETag headers work under IIS but not under the VS2010 web server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, cassini, etag, webdev.webserver

In my ASP.NET MVC 2 app, I have the following lines:

```
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));
Response.Cache.SetETag(lastWriteTime.Value.Ticks.ToString());
```

Using Fiddler to trace the HTTP streams, I can see:

```
ETag: 634473035667000000
```

in the Response Headers when running under IIS7, but when I'm running under the Visual Studio 2010 web server, this header just... disappears. Whether I set it via Response.Cache.SetETag() or via Response.AppendHeader("ETag", etag), it just never gets returned.

Is this a "feature" of the IIS web server? Is there some config setting I've missed? It's going to make testing cache invalidation a bit fiddly if I have to attach to the IIS process to be able to debug anything...

EDIT: It also appears that despite calling Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public), VS/Cassini always returns resources with HTTP Cache-Control set to "private"... does that help?

Comment: one after the other: `alt, d, p, enter, w, enter.` attach your ass to w3wp faster than you can say "debug"!

Comment: @Andrew... (1) I know, (2) it's Alt-D,P,W,Down,Down,Enter because there's normally more than one w3wp running on this box, and (3) there's a whole bunch of NServiceBus hosts and stuff running alongside it that makes debugging outside the VS debugger a little more involved than that... but mainly I'm just hacked off that it SHOULD work and it doesn't :)

Comment: Cassini has issues with some MIMETypes and headers.  Have you tried using IIS Express or full on IIS?

Comment: ah the dreaded multiple w3wp scenario. which one is it?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ETag will be suppressed if you use `HttpCacheability.Private`.

You can find more information on [Why does HttpCacheability.Private suppress ETags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32824/why-does-httpcacheability-private-suppress-etags)

If you change it to `HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate` it should work

Comment: I already had HttpCacheability set to HttpCacheability.Public, but Cassini was ignoring that as well - but you're absolutely right, setting it to ServerAndPrivate has done the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Simple - it's Cassini.

Cassini isn't meant to be a production server, but is there to facilitate debugging (which is why it overrides caching too - after all if you recompile and rerun would you want your new code not touched because a page is cached?)

If you want your debugging to work as it would in IIS then [IISExpress](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/860/iis-express/) is where you should be going... there's no attach problem there as it will spin up a real instance of IIS, but in your own user context.