# Why does my nested HttpModule EndRequest event handler not fire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I'm having some strange behavior when I try to modify my headers with a `EndRequest` event handler in a nested `HttpModule` on MVC 5.2.2 and .NET 4.6.2. If I don't modify `EndRequest` in my top level `HttpModule`, it appears that the event handler in the nested `HttpModule` never fires, even though I know `Init` was called on the nested `HttpModule`.

My question is, what is occurring in my code below to prevent the "TestNested" header from appearing in response headers, unless I include the commented out code that adds an `EndRequest` event handler that does nothing?

---

Dynamically register my top level `HttpModule`

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStartClass), "Start")]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class PreApplicationStartClass
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(TopHttpModule));
        }
    }
}
```

Call `Init` on all my other `HttpModules` from a single top level module

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class TopHttpModule: IHttpModule
    {
        private readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<IHttpModule>> _modules = 
            new Lazy<IEnumerable<IHttpModule>>(RetrieveModules);

        private static IEnumerable<IHttpModule> RetrieveModules()
        {
            return DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IHttpModule>();
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            var modules = _modules.Value;
            foreach (var module in modules
                .Where(module => module.GetType() != typeof(TopHttpModule)))
            {
                module.Init(context);
            }

            context.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var app = sender as HttpApplication;
                if (app != null)
                {
                    //This shows that NestedHttpModule was found
                    app.Context.Response.Headers.Add(
                        "TestModules",
                        string.Join(",", modules.Select(_ => _.GetType().ToString())));
                }
            };

            //Add this and the NestedHttpModule EndRequest handler works
            //context.EndRequest += (sender, e) =>
            //{
            //    //Do Nothing
            //};
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var modules = _modules.Value;
            foreach (var disposable in modules
                .Where(disposable => disposable.GetType() != typeof(TopHttpModule)))
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Modify some header information in an `EndRequest` event handler

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class NestedHttpModule: IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            //This gets called whether or not the TopHttpModule modifies context.EndRequest 
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;

            context.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
        }

        public void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app != null && app.Context != null)
            {
                //This doesn't appear to be called unless TopHttpModule modifies context.EndRequest
                app.Context.Response.Headers.Add("TestNested", "Found");
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Do Nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the obvious question is - why are you using an HttpModule to change headers instead of using MVC APIs such as [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) to do this? Why use complex legacy ASP.NET technology for something that is already [readily modifiable in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15165248/181087)?

Comment: Which version of Asp.Net MVC and .NET framework are you using? The  NestedHttpModule.EndRequest fires for me.

Comment: @CodingDawg MVC 5.2.2 and .NET 4.6.2

Comment: @NightOwl888 I want this change to occur on every request, not just for MVC actions. HttpModule or Global.asac appears to be the correct choice according to the question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507496/http-module-vs-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @ThomasLangston - You are right, if you want the header to be present in image requests, css files, IIS errors, ASP.NET pages, etc. it is usually better to go with one of these options (rather than using `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`). I was just checking to see whether it is really worth the effort to go down this rabbit hole if your requirements don't warrant it.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yeah, I've already got a functioning work around here, and I actually abandoned HttpModule for Global.asax for my project. This question is just to satisfy my curiousity about how HttpModule actually works in this scenario. It is very odd behavior to me.

Comment: @ThomasLangston Do you have a sample you can put online somewhere?  I can't find where this is reproducible.

Comment: @ThomasLangston, is this still active? Can you please answer your own question with what you did?

Comment: @PSGuy not an active area of concern for me practically. I went with my workaround by making my header changes directly in the Global.asax instead.

Comment: @ThomasLangston: Can you answer your question with the solution you used?

Comment: You might want to look at `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`.  I ran into a situation a couple years ago where the app was taking the request, doing something else, and redirecting without letting the request finish.  I believe this was what I used to handle that.

Comment: I've put together a Solution for this and it works completely fine for me, as it should. I'm not sure what problem you were having, but it's not related to the code you've shown here.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to modify my headers, but i needed to hide as much as possible. It is the same for Add or Remove or both, it is just headers.

1) You can set `MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;` in the global.asax

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
        }

and

        protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
        {
            Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
        }
```

2) You should not really use diff module for almost the same job, instead create a `HeadersModule` that only handles header modification, and use the `PreSendRequestHeaders` to add or remove any headers that you want. You can always inject some service with list of headers to add or remove.

```
    public class HeadersModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
        }

        public void Dispose() {

        }

        void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var r = sender as HttpApplication;
            r.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            r.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
            r.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
            r.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
        }
    }
```

3) To be extra sure, that some headers show, or "not" show up you can add this to your config file

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HeadersModule " type="MyNamespace.Modules.HeadersModule " />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
        <remove name="X-AspNetMvc-Version" />
      </customHeaders>
      <redirectHeaders>
        <clear />
      </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

4) Test all pages, aka 404, error pages, weird path names, cause they can leak certain headers or show headers that you did not expect.